# Graphiql variables not being passed to server

Tags: node.js, graphql, apollo-server, graphiql

I'm building an Apollo Server.  I have one simple endpoint communicating with Mongo.  There's a collection of announcements.

```
export const typeDefs = gql`
  type Query {
    announcements: [Announcement]
    announcementsByAuthor(author: String!): [Announcement]
  }

  type Announcement {
    _id: ID!
    msg: String!
    author: String!
    title: String
  }
`;

export const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    announcements: () => {
      return new AnnouncementController().getAnnouncements();
    },
    announcementsByAuthor: (author: string) => {
      console.log('RESOLVER: ', author);
      return new AnnouncementController().getAnnouncementsByAuthor(author);
    }
  },
}
```

In my graphiql interface, the announcements query works correctly:

```
{
  announcements {
    msg
    author
    }
}
```

The announcementsByAuthor query does not seem to be accepting the string argument, either from a variable or when hardcoded into the query.

```
query($author: String!){
  announcementsByAuthor(author: $author) {
    msg
    author
  }
}
```

Variables:

```
{
  "author":"Nate"
}
```

I've logged out from the resolver, and an empty string is being passed in, instead of the specified value for the author variable.  I'm new to graphql and I'm hoping someone can enlighten me as to what I'm sure is a simple oversight.

Comment: Is it valid to provide arguments without a query name?

Comment: Guess so: https://launchpad.graphql.com/w5v1rqj1nz

Comment: I see the problem. The arguments come in the second argument of the resolver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

`announcementsByAuthor: (doc, {author}) => {`

Comment: I regret that I have but one upvote to give.  Thank you.